# Custom sitemap handler causing site to fail to load (Sitecore)

Tags: redirect, triggers, sitecore, handler, pipeline

I'm trying to add a custom handler to my site to redirect to the appropriate Sitemap for the current language, i.e. mysite.com/sitemap.xml --> sitemap-en.xml, mysite.es/sitemap.xml --> sitemap-es.xml, etc.

This is my setup:

handler trigger patch:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <customHandlers>
        <handler trigger="sitemap.xml" handler="sitemap.ashx" />
    </customHandlers>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

web.config:

```
<add path="sitemap.ashx" verb="*" type="MySite.CustomSitecore.Handlers.SitemapHandler,MySite" name="SitemapXml" />
```

handler:

```
namespace MySite.CustomSitecore.Handlers
{
public class SitemapHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var curSite = Sitecore.Context.Site;
            var m_Sites = SitemapManagerConfiguration.GetSites();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry site in m_Sites)
            {
                if (site.Key.ToString().Equals(curSite.Name))
                {
                    var filepath = site.Value;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/" + filepath, false);
                    return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info("Error in SitemapHandler: " + ex, this);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It's not working though, when I try to go to mysite.com/sitemap.xml and debug it steps through the redirect process as expected and looks as if it should be successfully redirecting to /sitemap-en.xml, but the page just spins and displays browser error saying that the page can't be loaded.

I have tried a couple different redirect methods, but nothing has worked. I tried this as well:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;                         
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", "/" + filepath);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
return;
```

Comment: There is another approach that can be taken. You can create a job that will periodically update a sitemap.xml file in your root web directory. There may be a security risk in dynamically serving up a sitemap whenever requested; particularly if it's a large site. That approach has its own challenges, especially in an Azure PaaS environment, but it is something I've accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, But out of the box Sitecore don't allow .xml files. Security hardening.
You can use somethings like this in the config, to add the .xml extension

```html
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <preprocessRequest help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.PreprocessRequestProcessor">
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, xml</param>
        </processor>
      </preprocessRequest>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But I think a better solution, use the default and take security seriously.
Tell the search engine what the url of the sitemap is by using a robots.txt

```
User-agent: *   
Sitemap: /sitemap.ashx
```